# How to get Last post Id of custom post type in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-post-type

I want to get the last post id of a custom post type in WordPress. For this, I tried this code-

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>'soto_property',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'orderby'=>'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

$image_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ( $image_posts  as $post ) {
    echo $post->ID;
}
```

But It always returns me the First post id of this custom post type. I have tried `'order'=>'ASC'` also but it gives me the same result.

How can I achieve the last post id of this CPT?

Comment: This is just pure ignorance, sorry to say. You have asked this exact same question on WPSE, and I told you `post_date` should be `date`, but instead you decide to ignore me and ask this question here

Comment: I want to clarify you Pieter that I posted this question on both site at same time. I saw your comment at that site first so I also did as same as you told me but it didn't work.

Comment: Now we getting somewhere :-). Delete the `orderby` parameter completely, posts are by default sorted by date. If you have tried `ASC` as value to `order` and it does not work, then something else is influencing your query. How does the rest of your page look where you are using this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got my last inserted Post id using `$wpdb` query as below-

```
global $wpdb;
$lastrowId=$wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM wp_posts where post_type='soto_property' ORDER BY post_date DESC " );

$lastPropertyId=$lastrowId[0];
```

Comment: Since you do this with a full SQL SELECT query, it would be more efficient to only pick one, by adding "LIMIT 1" at the end of the Query

Comment: You also need to `post_status`='publish' or you will get all statuses, draft, private etc.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `wp_get_recent_posts` function.
Here's a sample function:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>'soto_property',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$recent_post = wp_get_recent_posts($args, OBJECT);
```

Check [function reference page in codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) for more information.

Comment: Hello sirblond.It also giving me first post id not last.

Comment: @shashank checked function on a few different content types (download manager and the custom one) and it fires me latest post as expected. Can you update your question with usage and results of `wp_get_recent_posts()`?

Answer (score 1):

try to use WP_Query

```
$args=array(
      'post_type' => 'soto_property',
      'posts_per_page' => 1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
      'orderby' => 'id',
      'order'   => 'DESC'
      );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);

    foreach ($query as $key) {

        $last_soto_property = $key->ID;
    }
var_dump($last_soto_property);
```

this will show the ID of your last custom post type.

Answer (score -1):

Your PHP code contains one small mistake:

`posts_per_page` is set to `1`. it should be higher than one. This is why you are getting only one result out of the results that were queried.

So instead of  `'posts_per_page' => 1` you could use `'posts_per_page' => your_desired_number_of_post_here`

**Your complete code should look like:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' =>'soto_property',
    'posts_per_page' => your_desired_number_of_post_here,
    'orderby'=>'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
     );

   $image_posts = get_posts($args);
   foreach ( $image_posts  as $post )
   {
       echo $post->ID;
   }
```

Comment: thank you Muhamad..for your reply. But with your above code i am getting many post but I want to get only one post and that post should be the last inserted post of that custom post type.

Comment: try using `'order' => 'ASC'` instead of 'order' => 'DESC'. That should work.

Comment: I did that but didn't work any more and produced same result.

Comment: Try using `$args` instead of `args`.

Comment: If the above does not work try
        $args = array(
            'post_type' =>'soto_property',
            'numberposts' => '1'
         );

     $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
     foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
      echo $recent["ID"];
     }

Comment: What do you mean invalid. And it is not `posts_per_page=1` but `'posts_per_page' = 1` and `posts_per_page' is the key you need to use to search the number of posts you need as stated by wordpress.

Comment: Either syntax is correct, one is string, other one array. You said it is a mistake, so how do you get only one post if you should not use `'posts_per_page' => 1`?

Comment: The question is about getting only one post but that one post should be the latest. That's what @shashank wants